# Recursive query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table

MyTable

```
rowNew  rowOld

1 ------- 2

2 ------- 3

3 ------- 4

4 ------- 5

7 ------- 8

8 ------- 9
```

I want to select query like this:

```
rowNew  rowOld

1 ------- 2

2 ------- 3

3 ------- 4

4 ------- 5
```

i wrote this with cte

```
with cte(rowNew, rowOld)
as
(
select rowNew, rowOld from MyTable
union all
select rowNew, rowOld from MyTable
inner join cte on MyTable.rowOld = cte.rowNew
)
select rowNew, rowOld from cte
where cte.rowNew = 1
```

and I got this records:

```
rowNew  rowOld

1 ------- 2

1 ------- 2

1 ------- 2

1 ------- 2
```

what is he problem?

Comment: How is your table different from your output? According to your setuo you can run a simple SELECT

Comment: This is some sort of hierarchical relationship, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your `where` condition in the wrong spot - it should be in the anchor query in the CTE definition to limit your starting point.

Also, you have join condition the other way round if you want to define parent-child relationship.

It all should be:

```
with cte(rowNew, rowOld)
as
(
select rowNew, rowOld from MyTable
where rowNew = 1
union all
select MyTable.rowNew, MyTable.rowOld from MyTable
inner join cte on MyTable.rowNew = cte.rowOld
)
select rowNew, rowOld from cte
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a93e/1)